# Can I use Azure v2.0 authentication to get access token for OneNote API

Tags: azure, onenote, onenote-api

Currently I am referring to this link for generating the token - 
[Token generation for using OneNote API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-auth)

Is it possible to use Azure v2.0 authentication principle and use that tokens to access OneNote api's which will ease out process for authentication as single authentication model can be used for both consumer and enterprise apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are accessing OneNote Apis from Microsoft Graph endpoint.

Refer to - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/authorization/converged_auth for more information on this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So if I plan to use Azure v2.0 authentication I need to use Graph endpoint for accessing OneNote content.  Azure v2.0 can't be use in combintaion with OneNote standalone API's

Comment: No, you can't - but Graph APIs and OneNote APIs are really the same thing under a different interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft Graph APIs - OneNote and Graph APIs are really the same thing under a different interface.

Comment: I know it's an old post but I would have to disagree with you Jorge. OneNote Api is similar to Graph Api but they are not the same. Graph Api will not let you create class or staff notebooks nor will it let manage teachers, students, leaders or members of those notebooks respectively.